# Questions about Flutterflow (refresh query, save dropdown, ID check)

Tags: dropdown, refresh, flutterflow

I have a few questions about Flutterflow that I can't answer.

1. I use the SwipeableStack element. I have now set that after 20 items an app state is increased by 1. Now I want a new API call query to be executed on that element and the app state to be passed as a parameter. To load page 2 etc. What is the best way to do that?
2. I have a multi select dropdown with options. When a button is clicked, I want to give these options with an app state to an API call url so that only selected items are retrieved. How can I save these options so that when you want to filter again, they are also selected and the Swipeable Stack is also reloaded with the parameters?
3. I want to save the IDs of the swiped items somewhere so that these items no longer appear in the as card. How can I best approach this?

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

I have looked at the docs of Flutterflow but can't figure it out and tried all kinds of app states but it doesn't refresh anything.